# Reading Files into 2D Array in C

Tags: c

This is a basic question but I seem to be having a little bit of trouble with my code. Im trying to read from a text file and print the exact same number to the console.
Im getting a seg fault, can someone push me in the right direction?

Basically I want to print the exact same numbers on the screen (not including the '4').

```
/*
My text file simply says the following:

4 //number of rows
1 3 5 7
3 5 7 1
5 7 1 3
7 1 3 5
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

FILE *fptr = fopen("key.txt", "r");
int inputs,i,j;
int matrix[5];
fscanf(fptr, "%d", &inputs);
for(i=0; i<inputs; i++){
    for(j=0; j<4; j++){
        fscanf(fptr, "%d", &matrix[j]);
        printf("%d ", matrix[j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}



return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the text file have *only* the numbers and spaces, or does it have the comment in it too?  In any case, check the function return values to make sure they're succeeding (`fptr` non-null, `fscanf()` indicating one field assigned, etc.).

Comment: Check the return value from `fopen`.

Comment: Only the number and spaces

Comment: in fact, you must check for return values for all library APIs.

Comment: My guesses would be that either `fopen()` fails, or the file is not plain ASCII and `fscanf()` fails to read `inputs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem in your original code is **int matrix[5]**.

you are reading in more than 5 values based on your sample text file.
the basic problem is declaring an array large enough to hold the amount of values you will be reading in.  How you determine that is up to you.

Based on your sample text file, consider something like this below.

```
/*
My text file simply says the following:

4
1 3 5 7
3 5 7 1
5 7 1 3
7 1 3 5
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NCOL 4
#define MAX_ROWS 10

int main ( void )
{
    FILE *fptr;
    int number_rows;
    int i, j;
    int matrix[MAX_ROWS][NCOL];

    fptr = fopen("key.txt", "r");
    if ( fptr == NULL )
    {
       printf("Error: failed to open file key.txt\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
       fscanf(fptr, "%d", &number_rows);
       if ( number_rows <= 0 )
       {
          printf("Error: value read for number of rows is %d\n\n", number_rows );
       }
       else if ( number_rows > MAX_ROWS )
       {
          printf("Error: value entered for number rows > MAX_ROWS\n\n");
       }
       else
       {
          for ( i = 0; i < number_rows; i++ )
          {
             for ( j = 0; j < NCOL; j++ )
             {
                fscanf(fptr, "%d", &matrix[i][j] );
             }
          }
       }
       fclose( fptr );
    }

    /* if the above failed because key.txt could not be read,
       then we will be printing out bogus numbers below.
    */

    for ( i = 0; i < number_rows; i++ )
    {
       for ( j = 0; j < NCOL; j++ )
       {
          printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
       }
       printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to print a space in the inner loop and a newline in the outer loop to get the output in the same format as your file.

```
for(i=0; i<inputs; i++){
    for(j=0; j<4; j++){
        fscanf(fptr, "%d", &matrix[j]);
        printf("%d ", matrix[j]);
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

**EDIT**: I just ran this in an IDE and it works fine and prints on screen in exactly the way you have shown your file is. If you are getting a segmentation fault, your actual file content is different from what you have shown us. Please show the actual content of your `key.txt` file.

Comment: The problem is that the program is segfaulting, not that the output is formatted incorrectly.

Comment: It doesn't. I just ran it as is in an IDE and it worked fine.

Comment: It segfaults for the questioner. I suspect, as Carl Norum said, that the problem is that fopen() is failing for them.

Comment: Update: I updated the program to include an if statement to determine whether the file was NULL and it in fact was. The file is in the same directory and has same name so I'm not sure but Ill hopefully work aroudn the issue. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1) I think your code can only result to a Segmentation Fault if that `key.txt` does not exist in the current directory (or `key.txt` does not contain your sample data above). So make sure that file exists with the correct content.

2) Try to program defensively, meaning that: check whether you actually opened the file successfully and got a valid `FILE *`.

```
FILE *fptr = fopen("key.txt", "r");
if (fptr == NULL){
   fprintf(stderr, "Error, could not open the file!");
   return -1;
}
```

3) If you want to define a matrix, you need a 2D array

```
int matrix[5][5];

// and in the loop you use
fscanf(fptr, "%d", &matrix[i][j]);
```